# Oracle Apex exception: Unauthorized URL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle Apex application and I'm trying to make a REST request but I'm receiving the error Unauthorized URL.

Here is my code :

```
declare
  l_clob clob;
begin
  l_clob := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request(
    p_url         => 'http://oracle-base.com/webservices/add-numbers.php',
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_parm_name   => APEX_UTIL.string_to_table('p_int_1:p_int_2'),
    p_parm_value  => APEX_UTIL.string_to_table(1 || ':' || 2)
  ) ;   
   return l_clob;
end;
```

The Error :

```
Unauthorized URL: http://oracle-base.com/webservices/add-numbers.php

Contact your application administrator.
```

[image]

Does anyone know how the reason of that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a firewall rule or something blocking that site to get this error?

Comment: I don't really know. This code is called from a workspace in https://apex.oracle.com Do you think this may work from https://apex.oracle.com ?

Comment: I entered the URL and it worked fine for me. I was missing the parameters, but I got the XML return.

Comment: The `anonymous block` in the backtrace would be the first place I'd look though.

Comment: Do you think such command can be launched from the standard workspace on apex.oracle.com or does it require some specific privileges ? Thanks

Comment: Webservices are usually wide open, because they accept specific parameters or error out. If you enter the URL in a browser, what do you get?

Comment: I get this XML : <answer>
<number>0</number>
</answer>

Comment: Same as me. So it must have something to do the way the call is being made.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a network ACL

If you are using Oracle Database 11g or higher, you will need an ACL to allow access to external network services. 
Here is an 11g example of creating an ACL to allow the MY_USER user to access "oracle-base.com":

```
CONN / AS SYSDBA
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
    acl          => 'oracle_base_acl.xml', 
    description  => 'An ACL for the oracle-base.com website',
    principal    => 'MY_USER',
    is_grant     => TRUE, 
    privilege    => 'connect',
    start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    end_date     => NULL);

  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (
    acl         => 'oracle_base_acl.xml',
    host        => 'oracle-base.com', 
    lower_port  => 80,
    upper_port  => 80); 

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Instead, if you are using 12c:

```
CONN / AS SYSDBA
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.append_host_ace (
    host       => 'oracle-base.com', 
    lower_port => 80,
    upper_port => 80,
    ace        => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('http'),
                              principal_name => 'MY_USER',
                              principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db)); 
END;
/
```

Regards